# Windows Server 2012 R2 Server logging me out randomly

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have tried many solutions but nothing worked so i am posting this question. 
Windows Server 2012 R2 Server logging me out randomly with an "Event Id 7002: 
User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program" after i disconnect a session via remote desktop connection. I have already tried, as suggested in this link [Disconnect a RDP-Session (with Windows Server 2012 R2) without the user being logged out](https://superuser.com/questions/1361165/disconnect-a-rdp-session-with-windows-server-2012-r2-without-the-user-being-lo). I have tried to change the settings for lock screen and screen saver, such that the user always stays logged in. Unfortunately, they also did not work. Is there a way to keep the user always logged in with out this Event Id 7002?

Comment: Would help if you included the session timeout settings.

Comment: @Greg Askew: I tried to change the session time out settings in group policy but it didn’t help

Comment: Computer Confguration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits -> Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Service sessions -> State was set to Enabled -> and Idle Session Limit to Never AdditionallyComputer Confguration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits -> Set Time limit for logoff of RemoteApp Sessions -> Disabled

Comment: You missed the *one* setting that logs off sessions.

Comment: Do you mean  Computer Confguration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits -> Set time limit for logoff of RemoteApp Sessions -> Disabled ??